# Possibly bogus SMART wear leveling value preventing OS X Mojave installation

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina 15. It has a 500GB SSD model "APPLE SSD SM0512F." It reports failing smart status even though the wear level count is near 50%.

```
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0036   053   053   100    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 17558115913881
```

From what I understand the current and worst values (both 53 here) are intended to represent the remaining lifetime of the drive, i.e. I've used 47% of the estimated lifetime. The 100 here is the "Threshold" value for failure. There seems to be discussion around the web that this is actually a firmware level bug with the Samsung/Apple SSDs, i.e. Threshold should be 0 because the value starts at 100 and counts toward 0 as the drive ages. Even if it is counting in the opposite direction, 53% probably shouldn't be a failure. What is infuriating is that OS X Mojave reads this apparently bogus value and refuses to install outright. Am I misinterpreting the SMART values? Has anyone figured out how to hack this value and just force the update to install? Apple seems to be just conservatively failing if there is any possible SMART failure even if the drive itself might be giving a false positive. Totally infuriating.

Comment: What are the rest of the SMART values?

Comment: 173 is the only value that is flagged as failing. Away from the machine at the moment; will post remaining values later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this but from what I've read elsewhere it works like this: The Wear Leveling Count starts at **200** when the SSD is brand new. Then it counts *downwards* as the SSD is used. The threshold is 100 and below that it is considered FAILING_NOW.